# Folder navigation on remote windows machine can't see folders with spaces

Tags: dired, microsoft-windows, tramp, remote, cygwin

I've been trying to navigate folder structures on a remote Windows machine with Cygwin installed, but I can't seem to navigate to folders which contain a space in them. Emacs claims that "File no longer exists; type 'g' to update Dired buffer", although I suspect that it's simply not passing the folder name correctly (interpreting the remaining folder name as arguments).

I *can*, however navigate to them directly by specifying the path within quotes. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I added the `[tramp]` tag. If you're not using Tramp for the remote access then feel free to remove that tag.